# Commands missing on command-line started from IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-8

I've used a IHttpHandler that compiles SASS files with compass since IIS 7.5. Ever since upgrading to windows 8.1 and IIS 8.5, it's not been working and responds with the follow message:

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  compass compile "theme/default/style/custom.sass" --trace --debug-info --css-dir "data/compass"
//
//  'compass' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
//  operable program or batch file.
//
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Here the portion code that executes the process (ref [Dado.Compass.SingleFileHandler.cs](https://github.com/roydukkey/Dado.Compass/blob/master/Dado.Compass/SingleFileHandler.cs)):

```
void IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    // Gather Compass Configuration Variables
    ReadConfiguration(context);

    string baseDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(context.Request.Path).Replace(@"\", "/");
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(context.Request.Path);
    string command = String.Format(@"compass compile ""{0}"" --trace --debug-info --css-dir ""{1}""",
        (baseDir + "/" + fileName).Trim(new char[] { '\\', '/' }),
        _cachePath.Trim(new char[] { '\\', '/' })
    );

    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        WorkingDirectory = context.Server.MapPath("~/"),
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        Arguments = "/c " + command
    };

    using (Process process = new Process { StartInfo = psi }) {
        bool hasError = false;
...
```

I'm running under ApplicationPoolIdentify and have given the same permissions. Also, compass is available when I try to execute it the command from cmd.exe.

**Why does the command appear from the IIS instance of the cmd.exe?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is a new setting in Window 8, but it seems there is now a User Path variable and this is the variable that was referencing compass. However, the IIS process worker is the ApplicationPoolIdentity, so it will not receive my User's Path specification.

The solution is to move the referencing location from the **User Path** variable to the **System Path** variable.